# Bat file for jar

Tags: java

I'm using a bat file to run my jar.  The code in my bat file is this :

```
@echo off
java -cp analyser.jar be.model.Start
pause
```

This works fine for windows.

But it doesn't do anything at linux.  I also need to be sure it will run on Mac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bat files are specific to Windows.  You would need to execute the command in Linux and Mac in a manner that is specific to those platforms.  The actual java call should work the same, I believe.  The one change to the java line would be if you had multiple items in the classpath.  In that case, you would need to use a colon as a separator instead of a semicolon (which is what Windows uses).  (Thanks to khachik for that tip)

For Linux, you would use Shell programming using a BASH script.  Here is a link that will describe what you need to do:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

For Mac, you would probably use an AppleScript.  Here is an article on how to get started with AppleScripts:

http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/index.html

Comment: 1) on mac shell scripts work pretty well; 2) The `java` command posted should remain the same, but if it contains more than one item in the classpath, `:` should be used as a separator, instead of `;` for windows.

Comment: @khachik - Nice one.  Thanks for the added info.  I'll update my post to reflect this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For Linux, why not use a `.sh` (shell) file?

As Biggs~ alreay said, the actual Java call should remain the same.

**Update:**

You will also have to make it executable by changing it's user permissions. To do this, use: `chmod +x thescript.sh`

Comment: the .sh file also needs to be executable, do this by `chmod +x yourscript.sh`